# Adding attachment custom field metadata to TinyMCE <img> tag

Tags: uploads, attachments, media, media-library, tinymce

I've successfully [added a custom field to the media upload dialog](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30666/add-custom-field-to-image-editor), but now I need (1) this field to be present on the `<img>` tag on post content whenever an image is inserted, and (2) a way to edit this on TinyMCE.

## The output

Currently it outputs the following shortcode:

```
[caption id="attachment_277" align="alignnone" width="150"]
  <img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-277" 
   src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/filename-150x150.png"
   alt="ALT" width="150" height="150" />CAPTION
[/caption]
```

Which then is converted into

```
<figure id="attachment_277" style="width: 150px" class="wp-caption alignnone">
<img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-277" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/filename-150x150.png" 
alt="ALT" width="150" height="150" 
srcset="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/filename-150x150.png 150w, http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/filename-100x100.png 100w"
sizes="(max-width: 150px) 100vw, 150px" />
<figcaption class="wp-caption-text">CAPTION</figcaption></figure>
```

However, I need it to be

```
<figure class="someclass">
  <img class="otherclass" srcset="..." src="..." 
       width="800" height="600" alt="ALT">
  <figcaption class="legend">CAPTION — $field</figcaption>
</figure>
```

How can I change it?

## Editing the value

I also need a way for the field to be shown not only on the media library dialog, but also on TinyMCE's image edit dialog.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/113367, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/124074, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/298155, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/193006, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/112294, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41603488

Answer (score 0):

Currently I've achieved a somewhat acceptable solution by using the [`do_shortcode_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_shortcode_tag/) filter as mentioned in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/252160), and using [`get_post_meta`](http://zz) to fetch the value, as mentioned in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/34445/22510).

There are (at least!) two caveats, however:

- The `id` in `do_shortcode_tag`'s `$attr` isn't the attachment post ID, but rather the CSS id from the original shortcode. I'm having to hope it'll be always `attachment_NNN` (where NNN is the attachment ID),
- The user can't edit the value on TinyMCE. It can be actually a good thing, because of consistency.

I'm hoping someone can come up with a better answer!